# get for loop data into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

this is my script:

```
 function createSlots(experiences){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var slots = req.body.availableSlots;
        slots = JSON.parse( slots );
        var count = slots.length;
        var array = [];
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
            var date = slots[i].date;
            var timeAvailability = slots[i].time;
            //console.log(timeAvailability);
            var availability = new Availability({
                'expId':experiences._id,
                'availabilitydate': date,
                'availabilityslots': JSON.stringify(timeAvailability)
            });
            //console.log(availability);
            availability.save(function(err,availability){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    if(availability){
                        array.push(availability);
                        resolve();
                    }else{
                        reject(err);
                    }

                }
            });


        }
        console.log(array);
        var obj = {experience : experiences, availability:array}
        resolve(obj);
    });
}
```

I need to get all inserted data from for loop into single array but not getting anything. why i am getting array. [] blank. can you please help me. thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling this function?

Comment: Maybe create an jsbin.com example.

Comment: @MathewBerg when i console.log(availability) it gives me single result. but need to get all loop data into single array. i can show you but. there are more functions calling before this function.  validateFields().then(createExp).then(createSlots).then(function(data){
        res.status(200).json({
            msg:'Create Experience',
            data: data
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        res.status(400).json({
            msg: 'Could Not Create',
            error: err
        });
    });

Comment: Are you sure that the function save of the objet availability is called? Are you sure that inside the save function the array.push(availability); line of code is executed? Did you put some console logs inside the save function?

Comment: @amedeoavogadro yes when i console.log(array); it gives me correct result first loop run it givs me one result in array after second loop it gives me 2 result in array..... but outside of loop it show nothing

Comment: Ok now i solve the problem. array.push() outside of the save function. now it working great.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createSlots(experiences){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var slots = req.body.availableSlots;
        slots = JSON.parse( slots );
        var count = slots.length;
        var array = [];
        for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
            var date = slots[i].date;
            var timeAvailability = slots[i].time;
            //console.log(timeAvailability);
            var availability = new Availability({
                'expId':experiences._id,
                'availabilitydate': date,
                'availabilityslots': JSON.stringify(timeAvailability)
            });
            //console.log(availability);
            availability.save(function(err,availability){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    if(availability){

                        resolve();
                    }else{
                        reject(err);
                    }

                 }
            });
            array.push(availability);

        }
        console.log(array);
        var obj = {experience : experiences, availability:array}
        resolve(obj);
    });
}
```